# Difference between GenericApplicationContext and XmlWebApplicationContext and AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext

Tags: spring

I work on a legacy application with a web.xml.

The applicationContext that is used is a type of `XmlWebApplicationContext`.

I would like to know what is the difference between `GenericApplicationContext` (and all of its children) and `XmlWebApplicationContext` and AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.

In addition to this, how can I switch from `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` to a `XmlWebApplicationContext/GenericApplicationContext`? Should I get rid of `applicationContext.xml` and use a `@Configuration` class ?